# HttpClient stalls for long periods of time, even with timeout parameters set

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I have an app that is doing a non trivial amount of downloading of thumbnail images and other resources from a remote service.

I'm using a single instance of DefaultHttpClient and a custom class that I wrote that schedules all of my downloads.  All downloading is run in serial on background threads via AsyncTask.  I don't re-run my download routine until onPostExecute gets executed in the AsyncTask.

This often works perfectly.  If I queue up 20 images, my scheduler does its thing just fine.  However, I run into cases where the procedure just stalls at the point of calling client.execute (where client is my instance of DefaultHttpClient).  I can inexplicably resuscitate the process by navigating around the app and doing random actions (scrolling a list, navigating back and forth between activities, etc).  **It's as if something I'm doing is sending a "wake up" message to a thread that has stalled or deadlocked.**

I've added an obnoxious amount of logging at all moving parts of my application to see if something external to this procedure is causing some kind of deadlock condition.  I view LogCat by pid to see if anything else is happening in my process at the point of stalling or at the point of resuming, and I don't see anything whatsoever out of the ordinary.  The weirdest part about this is that I can duplicate the exact condition over and over.

FWIW, I have set socket timeouts and connection timeouts on both the HttpClient instance and the HttpGet instance that I pass to the execute method.  This does not cause the execute method to return early or throw an exception or anything like that.  When the procedure "kicks back in", HttpClient.execute returns a valid HttpResponse and everything operates as normal.

Any ideas on things I can debug to find out where this is getting tripped up?  I recognize that this is a very specific condition, but **are there any advanced methods for specifically debugging DefaultHttpClient or http traffic in Android in general?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you share the same HttpClient across threads? It's not thread-safe by default, so you might want to check that. Most likely it's blocking on I/O though, so you should do some wire debugging. You can use something like this to enable HttpClient wire dump logs:

```
Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.wire").setLevel(Level.FINEST);
Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.headers").setLevel(FINEST);
Logger.getLogger("httpclient.wire.header").setLevel(FINEST);
Logger.getLogger("httpclient.wire.content").setLevel(FINEST);

System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log",
     "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog");
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime", "true");
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.httpclient.wire", "debug");
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http", "debug");
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.headers", "debug");
```

To enable it, execute the following shell commands. Wire logs will be output to logcat:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.org.apache.http VERBOSE 
adb shell setprop log.tag.org.apache.http.wire VERBOSE 
adb shell setprop log.tag.org.apache.http.headers VERBOSE
```

Comment: Thanks for responding...tough to get answers to such specific and long-winded questions.  I'm going to try the logging, but I believe you pointed me in the right direction anyway.  I'm using AsyncTask which gives me threads from a thread pool...this could be causing some issues.  I'm going to try a single Thread derived class so there's never more than one simultaneous call to HttpClient.execute on diff threads.  I'd be willing to bet that even though execute returns before I run my loop again, there's probably some cleanup that hasn't finished running before the next thread comes in.

Comment: Btw, I have added this code and I don't see any additional logs in LogCat.  Is there anything more to this?  Is it dumping logs to a file, or should I be seeing this in LogCat?

Comment: Should be going to logcat.  Make sure you execute this before your app's code, like in a static initializer.

Comment: I did.  I have a custom Application class that builds all my common objects and exposes them to the rest of the app, and I execute this code in the same method where I initialize my HttpClient class

Comment: Turns out you need to set some properties from the shell as well, I forgot about those: `adb shell setprop log.tag.org.apache.http VERBOSE` 
`adb shell setprop log.tag.org.apache.http.wire VERBOSE`
`adb shell setprop log.tag.org.apache.http.headers VERBOSE`

Comment: Funny thing is that once I enable that and it starts logging, I can no longer duplicate the error.  It's as if the extra cycles it takes to write out the logs is enough for it to avoid the deadlock.  I'm going to refactor it and I think I have a handle on a legitimate solution, but do me a favor and add the bit about the shell commands so I can accept this answer.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Glad to hear you have an idea how to fix it. BTW, if you are not already using it, you might want to have a lock at `AndroidHttpClient`, it safe to use from multiple threads. I added the shell commands to the original answer.

Comment: Am having this *exact* problem, down to the problem disappearing if I switch the logging on. Only difference is I already use AndroidHttpClient, which uses the thread-safe connection pool. I suspect a platform bug.

Answer (score -2):

I have had a similar problem before. 
When I try to do HTTP get in an queue, the method `httpClient.execute(get);` will not return a response, like deadlock.

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

This is my code, and what I do is call `entity.consumeContent();`then it works.

Comment: Didn't really answer the question.